# Chef: Increment value in a file each time the cookbook is applied

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, increment, chef-recipe, cookbook

One of my recipes echoes a static value into a file each time the cookbook is applied to a server, e.g.

```
bash 'example' do
  code <<-EOF
    echo "1" > /path/file.txt
  EOF
end
```

I would like to increment this value each time the cookbook is applied a server. So the next time, /path/file.txt would contain the value "2", then "3"...

Answer (score 2):

This is really weird thing to do since it would be non-convergent but whatever floats your boat:

```
ruby_block 'weird thing' do
  block do
    path = '/whatever.txt'
    value = IO.read(path).to_i
    IO.write(path, (value + 1).to_s)
  end
end
```

Comment: thanks! I'll give it a try and mark your answer as the accepted one if it works as expected. BTW, what do you mean by non-convergent in this context? As in; if I was to apply this to multiple nodes at the same time, each would have a different value?

Comment: See https://coderanger.net/thinking/ for more info, but basically when you run recipe code twice, it shouldn't do anything the second time. This code defines actions, not target state.

Comment: And this is purely local, there is no (non-terrible) way to do an auto-increment across multiple servers in Chef, you would use the shard_seed instead.